# why data is undefined when pass data from parent?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

for edit my fake list i am using axios.put. i get data from the action and pas it to my form component but all data is undefined.
i fetch one book from store and pass it ass prop to form component and in constructor when i use it , it is undefined. i the toturial i watch it is okey but now it is not.
tanx for help

```js
//actions
export const EDIT_BOOK = 'EDIT_BOOK';
export const editBook = (id, values) => {
  const request = axios.put(`${ROOT_URL}/${id}`, values);
  return {
    type: EDIT_BOOK,
    payload: request
  }
};
export const FETCH_ONE_BOOK = 'FETCH_ONE_BOOK';
export const fetchOneBook = (id) => {
  const request = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/${id}`);
  return {
    type: FETCH_ONE_BOOK,
    payload: request
  }
};

//EidtComponent 
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import BookForm from "./BookForm";
import {editBook, fetchOneBook} from '../actions/actions_books';
import {connect} from "react-redux";

class BookEdit extends Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.props.fetchOneBook(this.props.match.params.id);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BookForm
          book={this.props.book}
          onSubmit={(book) => {
            this.props.editBook(book).then(()=>{
              this.props.history.push('/')
            })

          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log('BookEdit Page: ',state.books.book);
  return {book: state.books.book}
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {editBook, fetchOneBook})(BookEdit);

//form component
class BookForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(props);
    this.state = {
      userId: props.book ? props.book.userId : 0,
      title: props.book ? props.book.title : '',
      body: props.book ? props.book.body : ''
    };
  }
```

Comment: In your `<BookForm>` component, what happens if you `console.log(this.props);`? Does that show the data you require?

Comment: it is show undefind but i want show to me {userId:...,title:....,body:...}

Comment: Can `console.log(this)` in your `BookForm ` constructor and update your post with the results?

Comment: console.log(this.props) back an object but in there book is empty

Comment: And what about the result of `console.log('BookEdit Page: ',state.books.book);`? does that log the correct data?

Comment: `console.log(this.props) inside componentWillreceiveprops(). `

Comment: console.log('BookEdit Page: ',state.books.book); yes show correct data